# How do you hack/decompile Camera firmware? (w/ decompiling tangent)

Tags: camera, firmware

I wanted to know what steps one would need to take to "hack" a camera's firmware to add/change features, specifically cameras of Canon or Olympus make.

I can understand this is an involved topic, but a general outline of the steps and what I issues I should keep an eye out for would be appreciated.

I presume the first step is to take the firmware, load it into a decompiler (any recommendations?) and examine the contents.  I admit I've never decompiled code before, so this will be a good challenge to get me started, any advice? books? tutorials? what should I expect?

Thanks stack as always!

Note : I know about Magic Lantern and CHDK, I want to get technical advise on how they were started and came to be.

http://magiclantern.wikia.com/wiki/Decompiling

http://magiclantern.wikia.com/wiki/Struct_Guessing

http://magiclantern.wikia.com/wiki/Firmware_file

http://magiclantern.wikia.com/wiki/GUI_Events/550D

http://magiclantern.wikia.com/wiki/Register_Map/Brute_Force

Comment: oh hell, I don't want to say that this is some kind of impossible task, but still a huge load of work for you espec. when you did not do something like this (e.g. dissabling copy right protection via cracking). A good start is to look into assembler language, since most programs decompile pretty bad into readable code ( http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Disassemblers_and_Decompilers - i recommend IDA ) . You could still give boomerang a shot ( http://boomerang.sourceforge.net/ ) but it had bad results for large executables/dlls.

Comment: Magic Lantern's Wiki has a ton of information on decrypting and hacking Canon's D-SLR firmware. I don't know the specific page, but both the CHDK and Magic Lantern wikis should have some info for you.

Comment: ha, yeah if it was easy someone else would've done it already i'm sure. fortunately I have some experience in assembly, but rusty. thanks for the decompiler suggestion. Also, I've updated the post to reflect some articles I found on the MagicLantern wiki that gives a peak into the beast ;-)

Comment: Note that CHDK and Magic Lantern aren't firmware, just programs that load themselves into memory and are cleared at the next boot.  If you just want to add some features to those programs and/or change their "look and feel", you can compile a custom version of those programs.  Actually hacking the firmware is very dangerous, one faulty line of code and your camera is bricked.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to know what steps one would need to take to "hack" a
>   camera's firmware to add/change features, specifically cameras of
>   Canon or Olympus make.

General steps for this hacking/reverse engineering:

1. Gathering information about the camera system (main CPU, Image coprocessor, RAM/Flash chips..). Challenges: Camera system makers tend to hide such sensitive information. Also, datasheets/documentation for proprietary chips are not released to public at all.
2. Getting firmware: through dumping Flash memory inside the camera or extracting the firmware from update packages used for camera firmware update. Challenges: Accessing readout circuitry for flash is not a trivial job specially with the fact that camera systems have one of the most densely populated PCBs. Also, Proprietary firmware are highly protected with sophisticated encryption algorithms when embedded into update packages.
3. Dis-assembly: getting a "bit" more readable instructions out of the opcode firmware. Challenges: Although dis-assemblers are widely available, they will give you the "operational" equivalent assembly code out of the opcode with no guarantee for being human readable/meaningful.
4. Customization: Just after understanding most of the code functionalities, you can make modifications that need not to harm normal operation of the camera system. Challenges: Not an easy task.

Alternatively, I highly recommend you to look for an already open source  camera software (also HW). You can learn a lot about camera systems.
Such projects are: [Elphel](http://www3.elphel.com/index.php) and [AXIOM](https://www.apertus.org/)